# Phoenix channels, How I kick a user from a channel?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework, channel, gen-server

So I am trying to understand the workflow in kicking a user from a channel. I have a command I can issue to the channel #kick username. This is handle by a handle in which parse the message and will detect is a command. That will call the kick function in my channel. My issue is how I actually make the user leave. There is no such thing as Endpoint.Broadcast with a leave event like we have for disconnecting a socket from everything.

I've been told to use a Endpoint.Broadcast an event like kick and use a handle_out to intercept it. Well even if I use it, how is this disconnecting the user I want specifically to be kick as an admin.